# Override django admin change_list with multiple admin sites not working

Tags: django, django-admin

I've exposed multiple databases in the admin site using the link here: [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface). Now, I need to override the change_list.html for one of the models exposed in the default admin website and add a button on the page. Here's the code in the file project/templates/admin/my-app/my-model/change_list.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hi!");
    });
</script>
```

Somehow this javascript isn't working. I've overridden django admin html before, but with this project I'm exposing multiple databases (kind of multiple admin sites) so is there something different that needs to be done to override the admin html here?

Answer (score 0):

you need to point to that template in your admin.py

```
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/my-app/my-model/change_list.html'
```

and I would use `django.jQuery(document).ready()` instead of `$(document).ready()`